# How setting browser language (ignore google translate)

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, vite, vue-i18n

I'm creating a vue project with en-us and pt-br translation.

The code below works, the message.hello is printed as "Olá mundo", but google chrome keeps asking if I want to translate to english from portuguese.

It's my first time using this stack, so I don't know if I missed something.

I really didn't find anything that could help me set the app language. I even tried to define the language inside Quasar configuration, but the chrome keeps annoying me.

The idea is get the locale from browser, but for testing I did it static.

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import langPt from 'quasar/lang/pt-BR'

const messages = {
  en: {
    message: {
      hello: 'hello world',
    },
  },
  pt: {
    message: {
      hello: 'Olá mundo',
    },
  },
}

const i18n = createI18n({
  locale: 'pt', // set locale
  fallbackLocale: 'en', // set fallback locale
  messages,
})

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(Quasar, {
  lang: langPt
})

app.use(i18n)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3):

You can try to add/edit one or all of the following tags in your `index.html` file:

```html
<html lang="en" class="notranslate" translate="no"> 
<head>
  <meta name="google" content="notranslate" /> 
</head>
<body class="notranslate">
```

- `translate=no` is a [HTML global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/translate)
- `meta name="google"` is [google-specific](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2008/10/helping-you-break-language-barrier) and apply side-wide
- `class="notranslate"` is also [google-specific](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2008/10/helping-you-break-language-barrier), but can be applied to a specific tag